# xpath for text between two tags

Tags: html, xpath

I need a way to select the text **between** two tags (the first `span` and the following `br`):

```
<div>
<span>abc</span>
defg
<br>
hijkl
<br>
mnop
<span>qrs</span>
tuvw
<br>
xyz
</div>
```

How can I select just "defg" with an xpath expression?

I tried using `following-sibling` to find the first `br` following the first `span` but I could not find a way to select the text between them.

Comment: XPath version 1.0?

Answer (score 1):

With this XML input,

```xml
<div>
<span>abc</span>
defg
<br/>
hijkl
<br/>
mnop
<span>qrs</span>
tuvw
<br/>
xyz
</div>
```

the XPath expression `/div/span[1]/following-sibling::text()`
returns the 5 sibling text nodes following the first `span` element:
`defg`, `hijkl`, `mnop`, `tuvw`, and `xyz` each beginning and ending
with a newline.

The XPath 1.0 expression
`normalize-space(/div/span[1]/following-sibling::text())`
will return `defg` - with no leading or trailing whitespace -
as the argument to
[`normalize-space()`](https://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xpath-19991116#function-normalize-space)
is converted to a string by returning the string-value of the node
in the node-set that is [first](https://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xpath-19991116#section-String-Functions)
in [document order](https://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xpath-19991116#data-model)
.

In XPath 2.0 and later select the first item in the sequence, e.g.
`normalize-space((/div/span[1]/following-sibling::text())[1])`
which also works in XPath 1.0.

Answer (score 0):

The `defg` text content belongs to `div` node as well as `mnop`, `tuvw` and `xyz`.
To extract the first text content `defg` only you can extract the entire text content of that `div`, remove form there all the child elements contents and then extract the first substring in the remaining string till the space   delimitator.
The exact implementation how to do that depends on tools and language you are using.